# Multer-sftp won't upload over port 21

Tags: node.js, upload, sftp, multer

The GoDaddy package my friend got doesn't have SFTP, what I am trying to do is use multer-sftp to upload files to remote server through port 21 as port 22 is not available. Shouldn't multer-sftp work on port 21 needlessly of disabled port 22?

```
const storage = sftpStorage({
    sftp: {
      host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      port: 21
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {

        mkdirp('src/public/uploads/'+req.user.id, function (err) {
            if (err) console.error(err)
        });

      cb(null, 'src/public/uploads/'+req.user.id)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
  })
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Are you getting errors? What do the errors say?

Comment: @Kenster yep, Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pejak\Desktop\node-course\QR-pic-uploader\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:569:19)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)